# MaterialCardview requires Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, themes, material-design, android-cardview

I'm trying to test my skills on new Google Material components. 
But for now I am encountering a problem with `MaterialCardView`

The building process tells me

```
The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat 
[..]
at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.<init>
```

With this clue I added
`style="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` & `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` to the `MaterialCardView` and also to my Activity in the manifest.

I tried also to change my Acitivity to AppCompatActivity  but without any success.

I also tried to set styles told by material.io documentation but without success !

Have you some clues?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your inflate code?

Answer (score 5):

According to Material Components 1.2.1 you need to do this:

- Depend on the library `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'`
- You'll need to have `compileSdkVersion 30`
- Your activity needs to extend `AppCompatActivity` (or [use `AppCompatDelegate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44896392/2444099))
- You have to use a Material Components theme

Source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

The easiest way to get started is for your current theme to extend `Theme.MaterialComponents.*.Bridge` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.*`.

Additionally you'll need to override the following attribute in your theme, otherwise the card color will be [broken](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131919351):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Don't set `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"` on the card. You'll lose color information (primary, secondary, accent,...) from your theme on every widget inside the card.

Don't set `style="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents` on the card. [Don't mix themes and styles.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIHXGwRTMWI)