# Resources$NotFoundException on Android 10 devices

Tags: android, android-theme, android-10.0

**Problem**

I've noticed a lot of unexpected crashes only on Android 10 devices. Crashes are pointing to missing resource ID in different layouts but I was not able to reproduce it even on same device and OS as I saw in crash reports.Weirdly enough, after hours of digging through google search results page 4 and further(I've got lost and results were in Mandarin) i found post pointing to Developer options -> Enable view attribute inspection. After enabling it on my device I've could reproduce it but it's still not clear how to fix it. Disabling it helped and app users are not seeing crashes there.

**Question**

Even though that helped I want to know what's the culprit of it and what is the right approach to fix it.

**Crash log**

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f040378
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceTypeName(ResourcesImpl.java:305)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName(Resources.java:2111)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.getExplicitStyle(Resources.java:1769)
    at android.view.View.retrieveExplicitStyle(View.java:6731)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5639)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:687)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:94)
    at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.<init>(SourceFile:121)
    at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.<init>(SourceFile:52)
    at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.<init>(SourceFile:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate$45cd3863(SourceFile:126)
    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal$5250870e(SourceFile:1366)
    at com.example.app.LoginFragmentBinding.inflate(SourceFile:1090)
    at com.example.app.LoginFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:66)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(SourceFile:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(SourceFile:797)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(SourceFile:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(SourceFile:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(SourceFile:3273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(SourceFile:3229)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(SourceFile:2466)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1483)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(SourceFile:797)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(SourceFile:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(SourceFile:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(SourceFile:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(SourceFile:3273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(SourceFile:17229)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(SourceFile:178)
    at com.ing.mobile.app.activities.INGMobileActivity.onStart(SourceFile:145)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7978)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3472)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="model.CustomerType" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="AccessibilityUtils" />

        <variable
            name="view"
            type="login.LoginView" />

        <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="login.LoginPresenter" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:liftOnScroll="?attr/myAppBarLayoutScrollingBehaviorEnabled">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:navigationContentDescription="@string/login__cancel_content_description"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/navigationCloseDrawable">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/login__header_content_description"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="?attr/myAppBarLayoutScrollingBehavior">

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                style="?attr/myCardViewFullWidthStyle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:contentPadding="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/card_content_padding">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="@{view.customerType == CustomerType.PRIVATE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_vertical_spacing"
                                android:text="@string/login__title_private"
                                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/login__body_private_accessibility"
                                android:text="@{AccessibilityUtils.makeWordAccessible(@string/login__body_private)}" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="@{view.customerType == CustomerType.BUSINESS ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_vertical_spacing"
                                android:text="@string/login__title_business"
                                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/login__body__accessibility"
                                android:text="@{AccessibilityUtils.makeWordAccessible(@string/login__body)}" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/input_vertical_spacing"
                            android:hint="@string/login__username">

                            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/username"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="@={view.username}" />

                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
                            android:hint="@string/login_password_hint">

                            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/password"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="textPassword"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="@={view.password}" />
                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                            android:id="@+id/login_button"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttons_margin_top"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_vertical_spacing"
                            android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onLoginClicked(view.username, view.password)}"
                            android:text="@string/login_label" />

                        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                            android:id="@+id/help_button"
                            style="?attr/buttonTextStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onForgotCredentialsClicked()}"
                            android:text="@string/login_help" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

**Attribute/Style**

```
<item name="myCardViewFullWidthStyle">@style/CardView.FullWidth</item>
    <style name="CardView.FullWidth" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
        <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/card_fullwidth_corner_radius</item>
        <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/card_fullwidth_elevation</item>
        <item name="contentPadding">@dimen/card_fullwidth_content_padding</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/card_fullwidth_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/card_fullwidth_margin_top</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/card_fullwidth_margin_bottom</item>
    </style>
```

And the resource ID #0x7f040378 that system is unable to find seems to be `style="?attr/myCardViewFullWidthStyle"` or at least something in related to CardView because that's where the crash is pointing in the layout.

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="?attr/myCardViewFullWidthStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:contentPadding="0dp">
```

**Setup**

Im using attributes because style/theme is defined in separated module and using material lib 1.1. It happens on prod app version with proguard.

Comment: Maybe it a theme problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989348/8301375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some more investigation with obfuscated builds found out that the problem was the missing custom attribute itself.

During the following lookup of the Assetmanager:

```
@UnsupportedAppUsage @Nullable String getResourceEntryName(@AnyRes int resId) { synchronized (this) { ensureValidLocked(); return nativeGetResourceEntryName(mObject, resId); } }
```

It could not find the custom style attribute.
It's only happening when dev option "view attribute inspection" is enabled on an obfuscated build.

Updating dexguard rule as bellow fix it

```
-keepresources attr/**
```